# How to create a list of lists in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

I need to create a list of lists in Ballerina. In java, I would simply say     `List<List<String>>`. How do I do this in ballerina?

I have the following code.

```
int[][] arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
```

I need to add elements to the 3rd list and it is not possible as below,

```
arr[3][0] = 4;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ballerina has multidimensional arrays, you can do

```
    int[][] arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
```

You can find more about them here [link](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/arrays.html)

In your 2nd sample code you don't have a sub array at index 3.
You need to assign a empty array to index 3 and then set it's 0th element to 4.

```
    arr[3] = [];
    arr[3][0] = 4;
    // or
    arr[3] = [4];
```

Comment: I tried this and my issue was when I wanted to add a third list it didn't let me. (E.g: [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [2,3,4]];) So I guess the number of rows is fixed after initializing?

Comment: Managed to do this by using arr[3] = [4, 0]. thanks.

Comment: Size of any of those component arrays are not constrained unless you explicitly constrain them. int[][2] pairArray = [[1,2,3]] fails due to constraint violation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a two dimensional array in Ballerina for this purpose. Arrays in Ballerina are mutable lists of values of dynamic length ([link](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/arrays.html)).

The following set of codes helped me to dynamically create a two dimensional array.

```
//dynamically initializing a 2D array in Ballerina v0.990.2
int[][] iarray = [];
int[] item1 = [];
int[] item2 = [];

item1[0] = 1;
item1[1] = 2;

item2[0] = 1;

iarray[0] = item1;
iarray[2] = item2;

io:println(iarray);
```

Output : `[[1, 2], [], [1]]`